# Starting a screen session on startup with ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gnu-screen

I'm using amazon EC2 for a service that I'm starting, however when I try and start a screen session during the startup script (which is ran during the bootup process) the screen never gets started. I've made sure to run apt-get install screen -y, however I'm not sure how to make the screen start correctly.

Any help?

-UPDATE-

here's the output from my manual screen command, I must not be typing the right something...

```
root@ip-10-245-118-68:~# screen -A -m -d -S game ./game/orangebox/srcds_run -console -game tf -autoupdate
root@ip-10-245-118-68:~# screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-root.

root@ip-10-245-118-68:~#
```

Comment: Please give more detail regarding the user you're starting screen as, and in general, the command you're using.

Comment: I'm starting the screen as root, and the command I'm using is as follows:

RUN_CMD=".$FOLDER/$MOD/srcds_run -console -game $GAME -autoupdate"
screen -A -m -d -S game $RUN_CMD

Comment: So, does the startup script/command you've given start things properly by itself?  If so, then what "startup script" are you putting the command in?

Comment: Can you start screen by itself (just try "screen", then try to start it up in the background "screen -A -m -d -S game")

If so, can you start the game server (try ./game/orangebox/srcds_run -console -game tf -autoupdate)

Comment: See my updated answer, particularly the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting `screen` detached. What happens if you try `screen -ls` to list your `screen` sessions or reattach using `screen -r` or similar?

The first time a user runs `screen`, it prompts for a profile and creates `$HOME/.screenrc` and `$HOME/screen-profiles` with some files under it.

Go ahead, as `root` and let it do that then try your startup again. Maybe it's hanging at that prompt.

You need to put an absolute path for your `./game/orangebox/srcds_run`. Instead of `dot`, change that to `/path/to/program`

Comment: the screen isn't listed. when I try screen after the rc.d script starts it asks me which theme or something that I want to use. I think it needs to be setup, however I'm not sure how to do that through the script.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of screen waiting for you to press enter can presumably be fixed in /etc/screenrc or in the user running your script via screen in $HOME:

```
    # cat .screenrc 
    startup_message off
```